# How to set height and width of rect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to set the width and height of rect using jquery but I am getting error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null"**

Following is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var winw = $(document).width();
   var winh = $(document).height(); 

   $("#mask > rect").width(winw);
   $("#mask > rect").height(winh);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="1024" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity=".75" />
      <circle r="140" cx="240" cy="240" fill="#000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjW6MGgwtjTAhXCsY8KHWcbCOIQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var winw = $(document).width();
   var winh = $(document).height(); 
   console.log('before-width:'+$("#mask > rect").attr('width'))
   console.log('before-height:'+$("#mask > rect").attr('height'))
   $("#mask > rect").attr('width' , winw);
   $("#mask > rect").attr('height',winh);
   console.log('after-width:'+$("#mask > rect").attr('width'))
   console.log('after-height:'+$("#mask > rect").attr('height'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="1024" fill="#ff0000" fill-opacity=".75" />
      <circle r="140" cx="240" cy="240" fill="#000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly! +1 for instant suggestion on this.!